# OpenBSD and Wireguard hub and spoke: spoke to spoke communication

Tags: routing, openbsd, wireguard

I have successfully set up an OpenBSD system running Wireguard [wg0] which I have designated "the centre" at 192.168.100.1/24. I also have clients successfully running Wireguard, of various hardware types and OSes, of IPs 192.168.100.0/24. The intention is that OpenBSD can NAT to the outside world, and the clients can communicate with each other through the central OpenBSD system.

What works (ping responds):

```
(wg0:network) -> 192.168.100.1
192.168.100.1 -> (wg0:network)
(wg0:network) -> 8.8.8.8 (for example)
```

What doesn't work:

```
(wg0:network) -> (wg0:network)
```

For the scenario that doesn't work, OpenBSD itself responds with ICMP redirects. You can understand this behaviour, but it isn't what I want. What follows is config that also doesn't work, but I thought might work: changing OpenBSD to be 192.168.100.1 **/32** and adding a route for 192.168.100.0/24. This causes no response (Update: Should clarify that I mean no forwarding occurs, so no request reaches its destination) at all to be generated.

```
# /etc/hostname.wg0
inet 192.168.99.1 255.255.255.255 NONE
up

!/usr/local/bin/wg setconf wg0 /etc/wireguard/wg0.conf
!route add 192.168.99.0/24 -link -iface wg0
```

I've seen some talk online about how BSD cannot send a packet out the same interface it was received. Under normal circumstances that is a sensible policy, but I think here is a valid use-case, unless I'm misunderstanding various blogs around the place.

As a point of information, this setup works with Linux at the centre: spoke to spoke communication is possible.

(Update) Here's my addition to pf.conf:

```
block in
pass on wg0
pass in inet proto udp from any to (em0) port 1984
pass out on em0 to 8.8.8.8 nat-to (em0)
pass in from (em0:network) to (em0)
```

Comment: Try turning off ICMP redirects with `sysctl net.inet.ip.redirect=0`.

Comment: @JustinLudwig Nice idea, but turning off the redirects doesn't start the forwarding.. Confirmed when I tried: it just doesn't respond at all.

Comment: Are you sure no forwarding is occurring? Try running `tcpdump -i wg0` on the hub while sending a single ping from one spoke (eg `ping -c 1 ...`). If you see 2 echo request entries, the hub's routing and firewall are working correctly (and you have a wg config issue with the other spoke).

Comment: Thank you, the `ping -c 1` was a great help. I will write up what the issue was as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

With many thanks to Justin Ludwig I found the answer. It was not where I expected it to be.

Running tcpdump with a ping count of one showed that the ping requests were indeed leaving the wg0 interface, because I could see it twice. I didn't spot this before because I ran ping indefinitely and didn't clock that it was duplicated.

This led me to something I didn't realize about Wireguard: putting an allowed-ips of 192.168.100.0/24 on the edge clients does not work if there is a more specific /32 route to other spokes.

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey= ....
Address= 192.168.100.200/32

# Central OpenBSD hub
[Peer]
PublicKey = ....
AllowedIPs = 192.168.100.0/24, 8.8.8.8/32

# Another Spoke
[Peer]
PublicKey = ....
AllowedIPs = 192.168.100.10/32
```

Using the example above, I thought that this client would have been contactable from 192.168.100.10 via the OpenBSD hub, but it isn't. I wasn't seeing anything using `tshark -i wg0` on this spoke, presumably because Wireguard was dropping the packets before decryption.

So, in short, deleting the Peering for 192.168.100.10/32 above caused traffic to flow as I would like.

Many thanks again to Justin for his help.